# N amount of boxes within boxes being drawn

Tags: java, offset, greenfoot

Here's what I am trying to replicate:

[image]

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
public void boxes() {
    setLocation(20,20);
    for(int j =0; j < 5; j = j+1) {
    setLocation(20+50*j,20+50*j);
        for (int i= 0; i<4; i= i+1) {
            move(600-(50*j)); 
            turn(90);
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

PLEASE do not write me any code, I'd highly prefer just a general explanation as to how I can make it so that the boxes being drawn do not end at the same point. I've been trying to figure it out for the past two hours with no luck and what I currently have is so far the best I've gotten. Thank you!

This is based on http://www.greenfoot.org/scenarios/3535

Comment: what boxes ? is this swing related one or what ?

Comment: the squares in the first image share the same coordinates as the center of square. and you also need to parameterize width and height for the squares, I think.

Comment: @FastSnail I'm new to Java and this is just a project off greenfoot that has a turtle which draws straight lines. I'm trying to make it draw boxes within boxes

Comment: Can you tag (or at least add to the question) the library which provides the turtle graphics? Because it's not obvious what operations are available.

Comment: @dhke I have added the project

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with the value you pass to the `move()` function, it should be:

```
move(600-(50*j*2));
```

the reason is that the length of each edge of the square should be shorter by twice the offset from the previous square, as it starts `offset` units deeper and ends `offset` units sooner (`offset=50` in this case).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for explaining! Didn't think it was that simple of a fix..

Answer (score 0):

The `j` selects a next square.
Ask yourself:

- nice to know: end point of drawing is identical with begin point
- you start by (50, 50) more inside. How do you come there from the prior end point
- *the new length to draw is how much smaller*